# MPAndroidChart bar chart issues in android

Tags: android, mpandroidchart

I am using [MPAndroidChart](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart).

- How to change the BarEntryLabels in to left in HorizontalBarChart?vHow to remove that projects from its bottom?
  [image]
- How to disable zoom ?
- While clicking on to particular bar colour is changing how to disable it?
- IN BarChart there i have added 6 months but EntryLabels is not properly aligned to corresponding bar.[image]

Code:

```
 BARENTRY = new ArrayList<>();
    BarEntryLabels = new ArrayList<String>();
    AddValuesToBARENTRY();
    AddValuesToBarEntryLabels();
    Bardataset = new BarDataSet(BARENTRY, "Projects");
    BARDATA = new BarData(BarEntryLabels, Bardataset);
    Bardataset.setColors(new int[]{Color.parseColor("#701112")});
    horizontalBarChart.setData(BARDATA);
    horizontalBarChart.setDrawBarShadow(false);
    horizontalBarChart.setDrawValueAboveBar(true);
    // if more than 60 entries are displayed in the chart, no values will be
    // drawn
    horizontalBarChart.setMaxVisibleValueCount(60);
    // scaling can now only be done on x- and y-axis separately
    horizontalBarChart.setPinchZoom(false);
    // draw shadows for each bar that show the maximum value
    // mChart.setDrawBarShadow(true);
    horizontalBarChart.setDrawGridBackground(false);
    horizontalBarChart.setDescription("");
    Bardataset.setBarSpacePercent(10f);


    barChart.setData(BARDATA);
    barChart.setDrawBarShadow(false);
    barChart.setDrawValueAboveBar(true);
    // if more than 60 entries are displayed in the chart, no values will be
    // drawn
    barChart.setMaxVisibleValueCount(60);
    // scaling can now only be done on x- and y-axis separately
    barChart.setPinchZoom(false);
    // draw shadows for each bar that show the maximum value
    // mChart.setDrawBarShadow(true);
    barChart.setDrawGridBackground(false);
    barChart.setDescription("");
```

Comment: Can you please share code of your properties which you have set for showing this graph

Comment: Please look that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the *"project"* legend part try this

```
  Legend legend = mBarChart.getLegend();
  legend.setEnabled(false);
```

To make touch disable set ***setTouchEnabled(boolean enabled)*** on your bar chart object like this

```
  mBarChart.setTouchEnabled(false);
```

and if you want to show all label you should try

```
  axis.setLabelCount(...)
  mBarChart.getXAxis().setValueFormatter(new IndexAxisValueFormatter(labels));
```

and also try [official documents](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/wiki)

Comment: Hi Somesh. I have another doubt,While am calling API and setting the value from that but the graph x and y values are wrong.How can i achieve that?

Comment: graph X and Y value ? Axis values you mean ?

Comment: I have solved the issue,may i ask you another doubt?

Comment: @SunishaSindhu join [this stackoverflow chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/50272/androidians), we can chat their.

Comment: i can't able to chat,Not much reputation for that

Comment: How can i sort the data?

Comment: all your data is in `BARENTRY1` so sort the array list before adding it in `Bardataset`

Comment: shall i add my code over here.i have done.But some issue are there.The value is not getting correctly showing

Comment: if BARENTRY1 sorts then the BarEntryLabels1 is not properly arranged with corresponding values.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/142881/discussion-between-somesh-kumar-and-sunisha-sindhu).

Answer (score 0):

```
  BARENTRY1 = new ArrayList<>();
    BarEntryLabels1 = new ArrayList<String>();
    AddValuesToHorizontalBARENTRY();
    AddValuesToHorizontalBarEntryLabels();
    Bardataset = new BarDataSet(BARENTRY1, "Projects");
    BARDATA = new BarData(BarEntryLabels1, Bardataset);
    Bardataset.setColors(new int[]{Color.parseColor("#701112")});
    horizontalBarChart.setData(BARDATA);
    horizontalBarChart.setDrawBarShadow(false);
    horizontalBarChart.setDrawValueAboveBar(true);
    horizontalBarChart.setPinchZoom(false);
    horizontalBarChart.setDrawGridBackground(false);
    horizontalBarChart.setDescription("");
    Bardataset.setBarSpacePercent(10f);
    Legend legend = horizontalBarChart.getLegend();
    legend.setEnabled(false);
    horizontalBarChart.setTouchEnabled(false);
    XAxis xAxis1 = horizontalBarChart.getXAxis();
    xAxis1.setPosition(XAxis.XAxisPosition.BOTTOM);
    xAxis1.setTextSize(8);
    xAxis1.setSpaceBetweenLabels(8);
    xAxis1.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#701112"));
    xAxis1.setTypeface(tf);
    YAxis leftAxis = barChart.getAxisLeft();
    leftAxis.setEnabled(false);
```

Do like this.The following issue will be fix.